# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (60630, 2) instead

Tags: data, encoding

```
#import the libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#load dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\P1\cattle.csv')
print(dataset.describe())

#creaete dependent and independent values
x = dataset.iloc[:,0:9].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,9:11].values
z = dataset.iloc[:,11:14].values
print(x)
print(y)
print(z)

#handle missing data
print(dataset.isnull().sum())

#drop missing values
#dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
# we will lose a lot of data in this way, so we have to put mean values in the missing places

#replace the missing values
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = 'mean')
imputer.fit(x[:,4:8])
x[:,4:8] = imputer.transform(x[:,4:8])


# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
dataset.to_csv('exported_cattle.csv', index=False)
print(dataset)

# OneHotEncoding 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', OneHotEncoder(),[1])], remainder= "passthrough") 
x= np.array(ct.fit_transform(x))
print(x)            

#Label Encoding
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)
print(y)
```

Why is y.shape == (60630, 2)?

Comment: What shape is `y` before you pass it to the label encoder?

Comment: two column data of animals.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

LabelEncoder takes a 1d array of class labels and returns a 1d array of encodings.

```
le.fit_transform(["Cow", "Dog", "Horse", "Cow", "Dog", "Cat"])
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Giving it a 2d input won't work. For example, this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3],[1,4]])
le.fit_transform(df)
```

will raise a ValueError: y should be a 1d array. Are your class labels really in 2 columns?

Comment: i am working on GPS data movement of animals. so I take 2 columns. one for longitude and one for the latitude

Comment: So the latitude and longitude should be continuous, you're probably not going to want to (or be able to) use them as class labels. I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do. If you could provide perhaps the top 3-5 rows of your dataframe and explain what problem you're trying to solve that would help. thanks.